# Libgdx Refactor a class with texture

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, libgdx

I'm teaching myself LibGdx and was following the simple game tutorial, unfortunately majority of the code is in one class. I want to refactor the code so I can use multiple textures for the rain that falls based on a random number.

I'll attach the Code for the main program and then the class I got started on.

So far everything worked except the Rain texture/img does not show on the screen.

```
    public class GameScreen implements Screen {
    public static FruitHarvest game;
    protected final Texture dropImage;
    //protected final Texture dropImage2;
    private final Texture bucketImage;
    public static Rectangle bucket;
    public static Sound dropSound;
    //private static Music rainMusic;
    private final OrthographicCamera camera;
    public static Array<Rectangle> raindrops;
    private long lastDropTime;
    public static int dropsGathered;
    //    private int random = MathUtils.random(0,1);
    private Drops drop;
    //Iterator<Rectangle> iterator = raindrops.iterator();

    public GameScreen(final FruitHarvest game) {
        this.game = game;


        // load the images for the droplet and the bucket, 64x64 pixels each
        dropImage = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("droplet.png"));
        //dropImage2 = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("droplet1.png"));
        bucketImage = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("bucket.png"));

        // load the drop sound effect and the rain background "music"
        dropSound = Gdx.audio.newSound(Gdx.files.internal("drop.wav"));
        //rainMusic = Gdx.audio.newMusic(Gdx.files.internal("rain.mp3"));
        //rainMusic.setLooping(true);

        // create the camera and the SpriteBatcher
        camera = new OrthographicCamera();
        camera.setToOrtho(false, 800, 480);

        // create a Rectangle to logically represent the bucket
        bucket = new Rectangle();
        bucket.x = 800 / 2 - 64 / 2; // Center the bucket horizontally
        bucket.y = 20; // Bottom left corner of the bucket is 20 pixels above the bottom screen edge;
        bucket.width = 64;
        bucket.height = 64;

        // Create the raindrops array and spawn the first raindrop
        raindrops = new Array<Rectangle>();

        long delta = 0;
        drop = new Drops(dropImage, 64, 64, raindrops, delta);
    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        // clear the screen with a dark blue color. The arguments to glClearColor are the
        // red, green, blue, and alpha component in the range [0,1] of the color to be
        // used to clear the screen
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, .5f, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        // tell the camera to update its matrices.
        camera.update();

        // tell the SpriteBatch to render in the coordinate system specified by the camera.
        game.batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);

        // begin a new batch and draw the bucket and all drops
        game.batch.begin();
        game.font.draw(game.batch, "Drops collected: " + dropsGathered, 0, 480);
        game.batch.draw(bucketImage, bucket.x, bucket.y, bucket.width, bucket.height);

        // Draws the Items Falling
        for (Rectangle raindrop : raindrops) {
            game.batch.draw(dropImage, raindrop.x, raindrop.y);
        }
        game.batch.end();

        // process user input
        if (Gdx.input.isTouched()) {
            Vector3 touchPos = new Vector3();
            touchPos.set(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY(), 0);
            camera.unproject(touchPos);
            bucket.x = touchPos.x - 64 / 2;
        }
        if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.LEFT)) bucket.x -= 200 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
        if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.RIGHT)) bucket.x += 200 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();

        // make sure the bucket stays within the screen bounds
        if (bucket.x < 0) bucket.x = 0;
        if (bucket.x > 800 - 64) bucket.x = 800 - 64;

        // check if we need to create a new raindrop
        if (TimeUtils.nanoTime() - drop.getLastDropTime() > 1000000000) {
            drop.spawnRaindrop();
        }

        // move the raindrops, remove any that are beneath the bottom edge of the screen
        // or that hit the bucket. In the later case we increase the value our drops counter
        // and add a sound effect.
        Iterator<Rectangle> iter = raindrops.iterator();
        drop.update(delta);
//        while (iter.hasNext()) {
//            Rectangle raindrop = iter.next();
//            raindrop.y -= 200 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
//            if (raindrop.y + 64 < 0) iter.remove();
//            if (raindrop.overlaps(bucket)) {
//                dropsGathered++;
//                dropSound.play();
//                iter.remove();
//            }
//        }
    }

    private void spawnRaindrop() {
        Rectangle raindrop = new Rectangle();
        raindrop.x = MathUtils.random(0, 800 - 64);
        raindrop.y = 480;
        raindrop.width = 64;
        raindrop.height = 64;
        raindrops.add(raindrop);
        lastDropTime = TimeUtils.nanoTime();
    }

//    public void randomDrop(int value, float dropX, float dropY) {
//        switch (value) {
//            case 0:
//                game.batch.draw(dropImage, dropX, dropY);
//                break;
//            case 1:
//                //game.batch.draw(dropImage2, dropX, dropY);
//                break;
//            default:
//                game.batch.draw(dropImage, dropX, dropY);
//                break;
//        }
//    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {

    }

    @Override
    public void show() {
        // start the playback of the background music when the screen is shown
        //rainMusic.play();
    }

    @Override
    public void hide() {
    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {
    }

    @Override
    public void resume() {
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        dropImage.dispose();
        bucketImage.dispose();
        dropSound.dispose();
        //rainMusic.dispose();
    }
}
```

Heres my class for the drops

```
public class Drops {
    private Rectangle raindrop;
    private int imageHeight, imageWidth, x, y;
    private Array<Rectangle> raindrops;
    private long lastDropTime;
    private Texture dropImage = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("droplet.png"));
    Iterator<Rectangle> iter = GameScreen.raindrops.iterator();
    private float runTime = 0;

    public Drops(Texture img, int imageHeight, int imageWidth, Array<Rectangle> drop, float delta) {
        this.imageHeight = imageHeight;
        this.imageWidth = imageWidth;
        this.raindrops = drop;
        this.dropImage = img;
    }

    public void update(float delta) {
        while (iter.equals(true)) {
            raindrop = iter.next();
            raindrop.y -= 200 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
            if (raindrop.y + 64 < 0) iter.remove();
            onCollision();
        }

    }

    public void onCollision() {
        if (raindrop.overlaps(bucket)) {
            GameScreen.dropsGathered++;
            GameScreen.dropSound.play();
            iter.remove();
        }
    }

    public void spawnRaindrop() {
        Rectangle raindrop = new Rectangle();
        raindrop.x = MathUtils.random(0, 800 - 64);
        raindrop.y = 480;
        raindrop.width = imageWidth;
        raindrop.height = imageHeight;
        raindrops.add(raindrop);
        lastDropTime = TimeUtils.nanoTime();

    }

    public long getLastDropTime() {
        return lastDropTime;
    }

}
```

Comment: You need to clarify what's actually wrong. "Textures not loading" doesn't sound like a verifiable, specific issue. BTW, you're leaking the initial `dropImage` that you're loading before the constructor.

Comment: The Rain texture does not show on the screen. Can you clarify how "dropImage" before the constructor is leaking? I'm still new to programming in Java and LibGdx

Comment: where is rendering method of drops in Drops class. you need to draw texture of Drops in your Drops class.

Answer (score 0):

By `drop.spawnRaindrop();` you add drops to `Array<Rectangle> raindrops;` in your Drops class but for drawing you use

```
for (Rectangle raindrop : raindrops) {
        game.batch.draw(dropImage, raindrop.x, raindrop.y);
    }
```

Which will loop trough `raindrop` array list in your `GameScreen` which is empty.

So either draw the array list in drops or populate array list in GameScreen.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I will take it into consideration.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be more careful as you refactor. You left behind your original Array of drop rectangles in your screen class, and you're drawing that (which is now empty). Then in your Drops class you are referencing the iterator for the now useless array in the screen class. And you're updating that empty array in the screen's render method.

Basically, the drops need to be handled in one place, but you're handling redundant arrays of drops in two different classes and getting them all mixed up.

It's not clear to me why you even have a class called Drops that tries to handle collisions with a bucket. There's no reason to move top-level game logic into a separate class, as that just complicates the code. If you had a more complicated game, it might make sense to have separate classes for tracking and updating various aspects of the game.

Incidentally, you're leaking a texture you load in this line:

```
private Texture dropImage = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("droplet.png"));
```

because you never dispose of it before replacing the reference with another one in the constructor. In LibGDX, any object that implements Disposable must be disposed before its reference is lost, or it will leak native memory.

The straight-forward way to allow multiple drop images:

1) Go back to your original single class with all the game logic in the screen class.

2) Load your drop images into an array for easier access.

```
private final Array<Texture> dropImages = new Array<Texture>();  // replaces your dropImage declaration

//...

// in constructor:
dropImages.add(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("droplet.png")));
dropImages.add(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("droplet1.png")));
// etc. as many variations as you like

// don't forget to dispose of them:
@Override
public void dispose() {
    for (Texture dropImage : dropImages) dropImage.dispose();
    bucketImage.dispose();
    dropSound.dispose();
}
```

3) Create a class Drop that extends Rectangle and has an additional parameter for the image type. You probably also want to make these sortable by image index to avoid swapping between Textures multiple times as you draw them, which causes batch flushes since you're not using a TextureAtlas.

```
public class Drop extends Rectangle implements Comparable<Drop>{

    public int imageIndex;

    public Drop (){
        super();
    }

    public int compareTo(Drop otherDrop) {
        return (int)Math.signum(imageIndex - otherDrop.imageIndex);
    }

}
```

4) Change your `Array<Rectangle>` to `Array<Drop>`. When you spawn a drop, also give it a random image index:

```
private void spawnRaindrop() {
    Drop raindrop = new Drop ();
    raindrop.x = MathUtils.random(0, 800 - 64);
    raindrop.y = 480;
    raindrop.width = 64;
    raindrop.height = 64;
    raindrop.imageIndex = MathUtils.random(dropImages.size); // <-- HERE
    raindrops.add(raindrop);
    lastDropTime = TimeUtils.nanoTime();
}
```

5) When drawing your drops, use the drop's imageIndex to pull the correct texture. You can sort them first to avoid swapping the Texture back and forth:

```
// Draws the Items Falling
raindrops.sort();
for (Drop raindrop : raindrops) {
    game.batch.draw(dropImages.get(raindrop.imageIndex), raindrop.x, raindrop.y);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your informative post, I'll definitely consider the suggestions you've made. 
The reason why I wanted to refactor this class is because I do plan on making a bigger and more complex games, but I wanted to get the experience or refactoring code with something simple first so it doesn't become insanely chaotic for me when I work on the larger project.

Comment: For clarity, I have a Drops() class already. When you say "create a Drop() class", you are referring to a new class all together or are you referring to my current Drops() class.